# How to log out from TeX.SX web page in new layout

Tags: support

I have logged in on a public computer. Now I cannot find button to log out the page. Logging out from general Stackexchange leaves my account active. Cleaning history doesn't help also.

Comment: On [meta.se]: [I can't find the logout button!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210017/168244)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you click on the StackExchange menu at the far left, you can choose logout from the options right beside the site.  This worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The new version is so antiintuitive for me that I was lost.

Answer (score 4):

Just another option: visit the `http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/logout` page and click the logout button.